# How do I compute a realization of h(x) given its PDF and covariance?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, parameter-estimation

[Desription of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIryZ.png)

I've added a picture of what I want to compute. In the nomenclature of the picture, I want to compute a realization of y(x) given the known distributions and constants.

Let's say y(x), random variable, represents the height of a line, with x being the usual x-axis.

The probability distribution function is:

p(y)=K * exp[−(y^2/(2 * s^2))) i.e. a Gaussian and K and s are known constants

And the autocorrelation of y(x) relative to y(x') is given as:

C = s^2 * exp[−x^2/(2 * R^2)] --> C is the autocorrelation function between y(x) and y(x'), which since the process is stationary will only depend upon the difference between x and x' (i.e. x-x'). Here I replace (x-x') by x.

where R is also a known constant

What I want to do is to compute a realization of y(x). How should I go about doing this?

Given the constraints of the known distributions and constants (s, R, K) I would like to be able to compute a realization of y.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181605/2921

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to compute a realization at times $t_1<t_2<\dots<t_N$. This amounts to sampling from the distribution of an $N$ dimensional Gaussian vector $X$ with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $R$ where $R_{ij}=C(t_i-t_j)$. Such a vector is given by $X=R^{1/2} Y$, where $Y$ is an $N$ dimensional vector of independent standard normal variables and $R^{1/2}$ denotes the matrix square root of $R$. $R^{1/2}$ can be computed using an eigenvalue decomposition of $R$: if $R=P D P^{-1}$ for a diagonal $D$ then $R^{1/2}=P D^{1/2} P^{-1}$, where the matrix square root of a diagonal matrix is obtained by taking square roots of the diagonal entries. This decomposition always exists because $R$ is symmetric, and the matrix square root is always real because $R$ is always nonnegative definite.

If you want to sample $Y$ "by hand", a standard algorithm for the job is called the Box-Muller algorithm. But one usually just uses a built-in library function, usually called randn, for this task.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand that the "randn" function will create random samples drawn from a normally distribution with mean "0" and variance "s". But, how  I take into account the autocorrelation function, with correlation length R?

Comment: @JQK That's the subject of the first paragraph. randn gets you Y, and what you want is $X=R^{1/2} Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, and sorry if I come across as not knowing what I'm doing (hence why I am here).  What algorithm, or method, can I use to compute X=R^1/2 Y?  Matlab code would be helpful, if possible

Comment: @JQK Matlab actually has a special function sqrtm for this purpose, so you can just do Y=randn(n,1); X=sqrtm(R)*Y. Without this function you would probably want to do [V,E]=eig(R); X=V\*sqrt(E)\*(V\Y). Or, because of the symmetry, V turns out to be orthogonal, so you can instead do X=V\*sqrt(E)\*V'\*Y.

Comment: Is the "R" in your equations what my original problem statement calls "C"?

Comment: No, $R$ is a matrix whose entries are $R_{ij}=C(t_i-t_j)$.